# Running Common Lisp on ideone.com?

Tags: common-lisp

I have been teaching computer science for a long time.  The languages most often taught are C#, C++, Java, Python, etc.  I add in examples from other languages such as Perl, Ruby, etc. each semester so that students can see the commonalities across languages.  I have been trying my hand at Common Lisp and have to admit that for the first time in nearly 40 years i have hit the wall with a language.

Common Lisp has me stumped with getting a simple example program to compile and run.  I need the code to run on ideone.com so that students can freely try it themselves and make changes to see what happens.  I would greatly appreciate any help i can get with this...a full week of struggle is about all i can take.

Here is the code:

```
(defclass employee() ;;class definition header
    ((empid :accessor employee-empid;;member variable accessible and preset
        :initform 230
        :initarg :empid)
      (name :accessor employee-name;;member variable accessible and preset
        :intform 'bill
        :intarg :name)
      (pay  :accessor employee-pay;;member variable accessible and preset
        :initform 10
        :initarg :pay)))

(defmethod infofun ( (p employee));;member method to allow two member vars to be changed
    (print "The Worker: " : (employee-name p))
    (setf (employee-pay p))
    (setf (employee-empid p)))

(setq w1(make-instance 'employee :empid 100 :name 'worker1 :pay 47));;instance of class for w1
(setq w2(make-instance 'employee :empid 102 :name 'worker1 :pay 57));;instance of class for w2
(setq w3(make-instance 'employee :empid 103 :name 'worker1 :pay 67));;instance of class for w3

(describe w1);;get general info from List about the instance w1
(describe w2)
(describe w3)

(infofun w1);;run the member function, change the member vars
(infofun w2)
(infofun w3)

(setf (employee-pay w1) 147);;change a member var by code


(describe w1);;look at w1 again and note the values
(infofun w1);;change w1 again
(describe w1);;look at w1 one more time and check the new values
```

I hope somebody can help me with this.

thanks

Dr t

Comment: You would need to check INFOFUN: a) what are allowed arguments to the print function. b) a single colon is definitely wrong c) if you call SETF it expects two arguments. You provide only one.

Comment: also: if you post a problem, you should also provide the error messages.

Comment: Since the failure occurs at run time there are no error messages.  Just no output as i expect.  I have been convinced that the problem is in the infofun function but i can't get it to work...

Comment: Probably then not a good idea to debug code in IDEONE. Get another implementation, write the code there, debug it and later run the result in IDEONE. As such IDEONE is not useful for writing code, if there are no compiler messages.

Comment: i changed the setq to setf...and now get compiler errors.  says that infofun (setf (employee-pay p)) requires two arguments...I have no idea what it needs now...I think i will give up for now.  good chance that i met my match in common lisp:)

Comment: What it needs is two arguments. What would you expect `p.employee_pay = ;` to do in C?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "member method" in CLOS.  Methods are not "attached" to any class, but to generic functions.  You need not use methods to use accessors, accessors _are_ methods.  Instead of struggling to map Algol concepts to Lisp syntax, I recommend reading a book about Lisp.  [Practical Common Lisp](http://gigamonkeys.com/book) is a good book for people who can program but do not yet know Lisp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are typos in your code: `intarg` instead of `initarg`, same with `intform`.

This line

```
    (print "The Worker: " : (employee-name p))
```

has a colon in the midle.

Some `setf` like `(setf (employee-pay p))` require two arguments, as you did later: `(setf (employee-pay p) SOMETHING)`.

I can see that simply by writing in a real IDE.

I suggest you get [Portacle](https://shinmera.github.io/portacle/), it's a portable and multiplatform Common Lisp dev environment that is straight forward to install: download and run. You'll be able to try your code with error messages. Portacle ships Emacs25, SBCL, Quicklisp, Slime and Git.

Good luck !

Comment: I have made corrections as you pointed out and did some more research and got the original code working properly.  I am going to get Portacle and work on my Lisp on a regular basis.  Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

I hate to answer my own question but here goes...

I spent several hours working on this last night in spite of telling myself not to.  If you are a programmer then you know what that is like.  Finally the lights turned on and i realized that my class header had a 'type' but no place for the interpreter to bind an address.  i just added a place.  then i was able to make instances!  I also simplified the class definition and took out all of the 'risky' code until it would run.  then i went back to adding behaviors back in.

Here is what i came up with.  I am working on a more better version.

```
  (defclass employee-worker ()
    (person-name empid));;extremely simple common lisp class definition

(defparameter *worker*(make-instance 'employee-worker));;constructor call for the first instance
(setf (slot-value *worker* 'person-name) "Joe Brown")
(setf (slot-value *worker* 'empid) "234")

(defparameter *worker2*(make-instance 'employee-worker));;constructor call for the second instance
(setf (slot-value *worker2* 'person-name) "John Brown")
(setf (slot-value *worker2* 'empid) "235")

(print "The first worker is: ")
(print (slot-value *worker* 'person-name))
(print "And his employee ID number is:  ")
(print (slot-value *worker* 'empid))
(print "")
(print"The second worker is:  ")
(print (slot-value *worker2* 'person-name))
(print "And his employee ID number is:  ")
(print (slot-value *worker2* 'empid))

(setf (slot-value *worker* 'person-name) "Joe Green");;change the slot values for the first worker
(setf (slot-value *worker* 'empid) "432")

(print "The first worker is: ");;look at the first worker again to see the changes
(print (slot-value *worker* 'person-name))
(print "And his employee ID number is:  ")
(print (slot-value *worker* 'empid))

Success time: 0 memory: 38056 signal:0

"The first worker is: " 
"Joe Brown" 
"And his employee ID number is:  " 
"234" 
"" 
"The second worker is:  " 
"John Brown" 
"And his employee ID number is:  " 
"235" 
"The first worker is: " 
"Joe Green" 
"And his employee ID number is:  " 
"432" 

I appreciate everyone helping.
```

Thanks
Dr t

Comment: Don't use `slot-value` until you know how CLOS really works.  Do use accessors and initargs.  Avoid partial initializations.  This is not a solution.  You just made the code worse until it "worked", instead of understanding and fixing the actual problems.

Comment: @Svante I am reworking my original code to fix errors and have made headway.  Thanks for your comments and help.